# Problem in javascript import/export used in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is there any problm is the following steps.

1- Suppose i have a js file `rough1.js` with the code shown below

```
export function exp1(a,b) {
    return a * b
}
```

2- I've another file `rough2.js`

```
export var x = exp1(1,2);
```

3- In `index.js` I imported previous two script as shown below

```
import {exp1} from './rough1';
import {x} from './rough2';
```

Now when i perform `npm run build` it shows in console that

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exp1 is not defined
```

So how to resolve this issue? How i will get my `index.js` to work with no error (recognising the imported value from one file in another)?

Comment: `abc` isn't defined, it doesn't exist anywhere in the code you posted, so why does it need to be defined?

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry that was a typo. its `exp1 is not defined`

Comment: well, it isn't defined in rough2.js ... you need to import it there if you want to use it there ... modules are very isolated from each other

Comment: just remove the swirly brackets, eg: import exp1 from './rough1';

Comment: @JaromandaX You saved my time. I was missing this simple stuff. Really appreciated

Comment: @Raphael that throws some error. The problem is resolved now as shown by Jaromanda and Chiragchavda.ks

Comment: Hi @Jake if problem is resolved then can you please accept the answer, it would be great. so anyone else doesn't have to save spend time on already solved question.

Comment: @chiragchavda.ks yeah I tried to accept that in the first place as soon as my query is solved. But there was a popup in browser stating that i have to wait 5min more to accept an answer and then i got carried away with my code. Appologies :) i Did accepted the answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see you need to use this statement in `rouge2.js`

`import {exp1} from './rough1';`

Thanks